# How to get Url referrer in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

There's a button in a page that will redirect to my website, how should I get the page url that redirects to my website in angularjs since we don't have access to the page redirecting

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(evt:any, absNewUrl:any, absOldUrl:any):void {
     console.log('prev path: ' + absOldUrl);
  });
```

using this is giving us the current page.

ex: (testingPage.html should redirect to myPage.html how to get testingPage.html url)

Answer (score 1):

The page should hit your website with a query string.

`example.com` should redirect you to `yoursite.com/?ref=example.com`, then you would be able to extract the query variable from `$location.search();` in the form of `{'ref': 'example.com'}`.

You can read more about `$location` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: then example.com should be modified in order to send this string to yoursite.com.

Comment: Yes the url on that site has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `window.location` object? Like `location.href`. You also have the `$location` object in Angular. [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

And then pass it as a parameter in the redirect url like myPage.html?referrer=...

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: yes, I tried $location but it's giving the login page url not the page url that redirects to this login page.